# Unable to open csv file with absolute directory

Tags: python, absolute-path

I have tried to open my csv with the code:

```
gdr = open('iCloud Drive/Documents/Python Practice/Kaggle_datasets/Goodreads.csv')
```

However, I get an error that there is no such directory. See picture below. I got the absolute path from the pic's bottom left.

[Finder on the left, Jupyter Notebook on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjTYY.png)

Comment: Probably the spaces from first glance. Spaces should always be avoided in filepaths

Comment: Does this mean that I have to change all my folder names and replace the spaces with underscores or is there a simpler method?

Comment: There's probably a way to work around it. I'm thinking it's recognized as a relative path because of it's lack of "C:/" for example. I only use windows myself. It might be able to be resolved by changing the current work directory. After some googling I see that an absolute path when using mac starts with `/Users/`, could that be it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Mac, but maybe the "Out of Space" text has something to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is due to space probably.

Try doing:

```
gdr = open(r'iCloud Drive/Documents/Python Practice/Kaggle_datasets/Goodreads.csv')
```